# MySQL select from many tables with multiple keys and values

Tags: mysql

I’m projecting an e-commerce web-app. I have to give the user a set of filters by many goods properties.

In my case, a item in shop may have a many properties, and properties united in collections. For example:

- Collection «Bikes» have a «Bryce type» and «Height» properties;
- collection «TV» have a «Diagonal» and «Technology».

A items have a `property_collection_id` key reference to collections table.

The sql query should select a bike with disk braces and height more than 17'', or tv with diagonal more than 100'' and plasma technology (for example).

The table structure is

```
#
# Sale item
#
 CREATE TABLE `object` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `property_collection_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
   `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'State of object, reference to other table',
   `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `object_to_collection` (`property_collection_id`),
  KEY `object_state_fk` (`state_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `object_state_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `object_state` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `object_to_collection` FOREIGN KEY (`property_collection_id`) REFERENCES `property_collection` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

#
# Collection of possible item property
#
 CREATE TABLE `property_collection` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `slug_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name without spaces and punctuation',
   `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
   `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
   `title_field` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

#
# Description of one property
#
 CREATE TABLE `property` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `slug_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   `type` enum('boolean','string','integer','list') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'string',
   `require` enum('1','0') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `property_collection_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `sort` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
   `units` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `property_to_collection` (`property_collection_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `property_to_collection` FOREIGN KEY (`property_collection_id`) REFERENCES `property_collection` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

#
# Item property values
#
 CREATE TABLE `property_values` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `object_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `property_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `value_to_object` (`object_id`),
  KEY `value_to_property` (`property_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `value_to_property` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `property` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `value_to_object` FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) REFERENCES `real_estate_object` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=161 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Code in http://pastebin.com/zJNApskJ

The query that I create is not (and will not) work:

```
SELECT `object`.* FROM `object` 
LEFT JOIN `property_values` ON `object`.`id` = `property_values`.`object_id` 
LEFT JOIN `property` ON `property_values`.`property_id` = `property`.`id` 
WHERE 
(
    ((`property_values`.`value`='7') AND (`property_values`.`value`='1')) 
    AND 
    (CAST(`property_values`.`value` AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN '0' AND '100')
) 
AND 
(`object`.`property_collection_id`='2') GROUP BY `object`.`id`
```

How should I create this query?

Comment: missing `object_state` and `real_estate_object` ddl.. how can property_values.value be equal to 7 and 1 at same time

Comment: Not `real_estate_object`, just `object`, sorry, old paste.

Answer (score 0):

Your query must reflect the dependency of the tables. Something like

```
SELECT ... 
FROM object o
INNER JOIN property_collections pc ON pc.id                    = o.property_collection_id
INNER JOIN property p              ON p.property_collection_id = pc.id
INNER JOIN property_value pv       ON pv.property_id           = p.id 
WHERE ...
```

And, as Amdixon already pointed out, you probably meant to say

```
WHERE pv.value IN ('1','7')
```

As the original `AND` condition would always be `false`. However, I suspect, that you would have to check on the `property_collection_id` first, in order to make sure, which product type you are actually looking at. Whithout furher data it is impossible to come up with a likely solution.

Comment: Thank for answer,  but I think, it's not possible.

If I need a property **between** two values, and property == value (like in my example about TV's) at same time, I can't use `IN`. 

May be I'll try mongodb or something else. 

And sorry my terrible English.

Comment: Well, `between` *is* actually part of standard SQL and does exactly what you want: look for values between some min and max values. So, you could use: `WHERE pv.value BETWEEN 1 AND 7`.